# Dynamic number of columns in SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql, dynamic, recursion

I have two tables.

item:
- rowid number
- categoryid number (foreign key to category rowid)

category:
- rowid number
- parentid number (foreign key to this table's rowid

The thing is an item has a category and a category can have subcategories recursively. This way, if I have the following tables:

```
items
0 - 3
1 - 4

categories
1 - null
2 - 1
3 - 2
4 - null
```

this means item 0's category is 3, which is a subgroup of category 2 which is a subgroupd of category 1. And item 1's category is 4, which has no more levels.

I'd like a query that returns item's rowid, the lowest level category and another column for each category level

```
item.rowid categories.rowid
0 | 3 | 2 | 1
1 | 4
```

Or at least

```
0 | 3,2,1
1 | 4
```

My problem comes with recursivity and a dynamic number of columns as response in the first case.

The reason why I want this done at sql level is because ultimately the results will be ordered by category, and I'd like to give the PostgreSQL server the responsibility for it.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I think you can obtain the second expected result using WITH RECURSIVE and ARRAY_AGG

Comment: Thanks, didn't even try yet. Will keep this updated